# composite expression value assigned to wider type

Tags: c

following is extract from the book MISRA C:2012 which I am unable to understand

The value of composite expression (+ ,- ,* ,/ ,&, |, ^, <<, >>, ?:) shall not be assigned to an object with wider type.

Example:

```
u32a = u16a + u16b;     //non - compliant to MISRA C guidelines
```

where u16 is uint16_t and u32 is uint32_t.

Will this cause any issue during program run ? we might need to use u32a as u16a might cause integer overflow in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "shall not"? The code is "non-compliant" with what? Certainly not C, assuming the `typedef`s you mention.

Comment: this is C .. i am reading MISRA C : 2012 and in this part I am unable to understand what could be the problem with wider data type

Comment: "shall not" means it should not be used in your source code. non - complaint to MISRA C guidelines

Comment: I suppose this is because you never know how your compiler will deal with (u16a + u16b) expression, since it may consider to store the result in 16-bits as well, before assigning it to target variable.

Comment: will it be a issue to store 16-bits value into 32 bit object other than space loss?

Comment: I wont be an issue, but you expect (wrongly) that there is no overflow possible, while it is absolutely possible. Writing the assignment as recommended by MISRA simply makes you see clearly this problem of overflow.

Comment: ok. i got that. thanks!!

Comment: @archie, that's the answer.

Comment: @Ben, I put it into the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you never know how your compiler will deal with (u16a + u16b) expression, since it may consider to store the result in 16-bits as well, before assigning it to target variable (consider 8 and 16 bit targets used in embedded systems).

You expect (wrongly) that there is no overflow possible, while it is absolutely possible. Writing the assignment as recommended by MISRA simply makes you see clearly this problem of overflow.